# BitBlt draws a blank image

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using MFC, and I'm trying to draw an image to the screen.  I've got the following OnDraw function:

```
void CgraphicstestView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
 CgraphicstestDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
 ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
 if (!pDoc)
  return;

 m_Bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_WALL); // m_Bitmap is a CBitmap member of CgraphicstestView
                                   // IDB_WALL is a .png resource
 CDC dcMemory;
 dcMemory.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
 dcMemory.SelectObject(&m_Bitmap);
 pDC->BitBlt(10, 10, 32, 32, &dcMemory, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

This will draw to the screen, but the destination area is blank.  BitBlt is working, since changing SRCCOPY to BLACKNESS draws a black rectangle.  Anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to guess that the problem is that your image is somehow invalid.  Because I tested it and it works fine.  LoadBitmap returns an HBITMAP, so you could test it like this:

```
HBITMAP hresult = m_Bitmap.LoadBitmap(IDB_WALL);
assert(hresult);
```

Comment: Sure enough, that assert failed.  Now to figure out why it's invalid.  Are there any common gotchas in putting images in .rc files? The image shows up fine when I view it in the resource view.

Comment: @Max: You mention that IDB_WALL is a PNG resource. `LoadBitmap` can load only bitmap (BMP) files, even though the resource editor may be able to display other formats.

Comment: @casablanca:  ...ugh.  That should have been obvious.  +1 for pointing that out.  Thanks for your help.